# Bootstrap 3 updates shakes UI when a Bootstrap dialog opens or closes. How can I get rid of this behavior?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have observed when bootstrap dialog opens, body tag of html gets following css.

```
<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;">
```

I think this is causing the UI to shake. How can I get rid of this weird behavior.
I have created fiddle. But this issue is not produced there. But in my local environment I am able to reproduce this. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpszz3j9/2/)

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: @TBAG ! yup thats true and that small change might take alot of head-breaking , ur better off opening an issue on git . though i am not sure how adverse this problem is ;)

Comment: Does this problem occur on all browser or only on a selected few ?

Comment: Its in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your css:

```
.modal-open {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I wanted to know why this is happening. Is it feature introduced in Bootstrap3?

Comment: Yes it is :) Apparently to compensate for the side scrollbar width

Answer (score 1):

I fixed issue by

```
body.modal-open {
padding-right: 0px !important;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```